# Getting error to install rlwrap

Tags: oracle-golden-gate, rlwrap

I am trying to install rlwrap for Oracle Goldengate installation but at the time of installation I got following error.

**yum install rlwrap-0.37-1.el6.i686.rpm
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Cannot open: rlwrap-0.37-1.el6.i686.rpm. Skipping.
Error: Nothing to do**

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Please change the tag to rlwrap. Not lrwrap

Answer (score 0):

The yum tool requires to package names as arguments not rpm files. Please run instead:

```
yum install rlwrap
```

If you have downloaded rpm locally then run

```
rpm -i rlwrap-0.37-1.el6.i686.rpm
```

Answer (score 0):

I documented the process here for Classic Architecture: https://www.dbasolved.com/2016/08/rlwrap-with-goldengate-ggsci/

In Microservices Architecture, rlwrap is included with the AdminClient.